# PropertySheet Full Screen

Tags: windows, mfc, windows-mobile, fullscreen, propertysheet

I'm porting an application from windows Pocket PC2003 to Windows Mobile 6.5.
On startup my application shows a PropertySheet with two Pages which I want
to show in full screen mode.

The problem is this:

What ever I do the Taskbar and the menubar will never disapear. Windows Button, 
SIP-Button and all other Buttons stay in foreground.

I tried this:

```
    CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    // Call SHInitDialog with flags for full screen.
    SHINITDLGINFO shidi;

    shidi.dwMask = SHIDIM_FLAGS;
    shidi.dwFlags = SHIDIF_FULLSCREENNOMENUBAR;
    shidi.hDlg = m_hWnd;

    ::SHInitDialog(&shidi);

    // SHFullScreen fails if dialog box is not foreground.
    SetForegroundWindow();  
    SHFullScreen(m_hWnd, SHFS_HIDESIPBUTTON | SHFS_HIDETASKBAR | SHFS_HIDESTARTICON);
```

and in normal dialogs it will work with 
        m_bFullScreen = FALSE; 
on top but m_bFullScreen is not available for CPropertySheet.

Has anyone any solution for this problem?